# Selenium Webdriver How to scrape text?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here's the website code:

```
<div class="question-row clearfix " lang="en">
    <div class="qquestion qtext  ">
        five
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to scrape the text (in this example, it's 'five'). Here's my current code:

```
qtitle = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='prompt-row'div/div"))).get_attribute("text")
```

However when I run it, this error code comes up:

```
  File "C:\Users\lycop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

That's all it says. Any help on solving this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the text **five** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.qquestion.qtext").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='qquestion qtext  ']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the `innerText` of an element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.save[type='submit'][onclick]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='save' and text()='save'][@type='submit' and @onclick]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Now it comes up with the error: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='qquestion qtext']"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)". I think this is because the page hasn't loaded entirely yet, which is why I used 'WebDriverWait'. How would I implement WebDriverWait into this as well?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.